# default value at declaration time

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to declare the value of an object (I'm interested in `int`/`double`) at declaration time, inside a class declaration? Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   MyInt<1> my_int;
};
```

is there a library implementing this?

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can provide default initializers inside the class definition:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a = 11;

    Foo() = default;   // still a trivial class :-)
};
```

In previous times, you'd have to use the constructor initializer:

```
struct Bar
{
    int b;
    Bar() : b(11) { }  // non-trivial constructor :-(
};
```

Usage:

```
Foo x;
Bar y;
assert(x.a == 11 && y.b == 11);
```

---

Maybe you might find @Msalters's solution useful:

```
template <typename T, T InitVal>
struct InitializedType
{
    typedef T type;
    static type const initial_value = InitVal;  // with restrictions

    type &       operator()       { return x; }
    type const & operator() const { return x; }

    InitializedType() : x(Initval) { }

private:
    type x;
};
```

Now you can add `InitializedType<int, 11> n;` to get something that looks like an `int` but starts out with value `11`.

Comment: (not my vote) It doesn't exactly give you the requested syntax, but that would be trivial to add: `template<int I> struct MyInt { int value = I; };`. The advantage of the latter is that you can retrieve the default value `I` from the type via Template Metaprogramming.

Comment: The OP's syntax looks like painful and troublesome workaround for smth that is very simple in C++11.

Comment: @KerrekSB: no c++11, only c++03, sorry. No explicit initialization, it is just what I want to avoid, I've a lot of parameter, and I to be forced by the compiler to initialized all of them.

Comment: @MSalters: I know how to implement this template class, but I'm searching for something better, for example with lock features and so on.

Comment: @wiso: Now I don't understand: You want at once to *not* have explicit initialization, but *also* be "force to initialize"? How does that work?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I want a procedure that force me to initialize a variable. Sorry, I've used a wrong terminology. I don't want to write `my_int=10` or `:my_int(10)` in the constructor